# Javascript animation very slow in Android HTML5 website

Tags: javascript, android, animation, cordova

I have a little HTML5 web app for mobile devices (running inside PhoneGap/Cordova). I animate some elements, moving them around the screen modifying the "left/top" properties over a function called frequently (by a "setInterval").

The performance is excellent on iOS, but really slow in most android devices.

Is there any way to improve the performance in that kind of animation?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setInterval is not the way for animations, use requestAnimFrame

http://paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/

Comment: You are probably wrong, if you check this page https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/DOM/window.requestAnimationFrame#Browser_compatibility[/link] you will see that the Android Browser is not compatible with requestAnimFrame...